# Shadow Removal by inverse laplacian in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, geometry

I have some query to code the algorithm in
[Removing shadows from images](https://www.cs.sfu.ca/~mark/ftp/Eccv02/shadowless.pdf) by finlayson

I have gotten the matlab code to get [illumination invariance image](https://rsu.data61.csiro.au/people/jalvarez/research_bbdd.php) by jose alvarez and convert it to c++ coding

I have continued to follow the image reconstruction step outlined by finlayson algorithm but was stumped at the part of the Possion equation which is the part after removing the shadow edge from the log channel image

How should I proceed after that. The discussion of this part is vague to me. SI have read the [following presentation slides](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiijrzAwIbhAhXG73MBHTBjDE8QFjABegQICRAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcs.haifa.ac.il%2Fhagit%2Fcourses%2Fseminars%2FshadowRemoval%2FPresentations%2FLecture08_IlluminationInvarantImage%2520Finlayson.ppt&usg=AOvVaw37lOnuPciTXQ_shqP1VUGc). It say I must perform a inverse laplace operation on the image.

what should i do ? inverse laplace is not so common to code. Would need any advice I could get

ThANKS

Comment: There is a lot to your question. In the paper, Finlayson points out (without fully explaining because he assumes some familiarity by his advanced readers) that the Laplacian, a second-order derivative, is the divergence (a first-order derivative) of the gradient (another kind of first-order derivative). Before I say more, how much sense does what I have already written make to you? Questions?

Comment: I presume that is to apply edge detector in x direction to x gradient image and edge detector in y direction to the y gradient image

Comment: (Consider prefacing comments to my attention with the handle "@thb". Otherwise, since the comment is under your question and not under my answer, the system might not alert me.) Logical. However, to evaluate the x gradient you must choose a particular value for y, and to evaluate the y gradient you must choose a particular value for x. The values you are *choosing* are the very values you are trying to determine. I am not an expert on image processing specifically (my background is in radar), but it does not sound to me as though your last suggestion would *quite* work.

Comment: In Finlayson's paper, under his equation (13), an inline equation appears in parentheses. Have you enough information to solve or apply that one? He has mistypeset the derivative notation, meaning to use Jacobi's symbol ∂ rather than *d*, but otherwise, he is telling you there how to calculate the Laplacian in a single step.

Comment: I am not sure how much any of what I am writing is helping. I know a fair bit of vector calculus but, of course, a Stack Overflow comment column is not the place for me to dump a textbook full of information. If there is a specific, narrower point to which you can guide my answer, let me know.

Comment: @tbh This page http://file.scirp.org/Html/6-2630030_32770.htm#ref8  Section 4 offers some glimpse to how to recover the image. I will try it out and have a look

Comment: Laplacian operator must be discretized over some domain, for instance part of the image, or the whole image. So you will have a linear equation for each node (pixel) involving only the pixel neighbors. You can create a linear matrix system where most of the values are zero (sparse). Once discretized you should provide discrete values at the boundaries of the domain (boundary conditions). Those values go to the right hand side (RHS). Also the RHS of the Poisson equation goes to the RHS of the linear system. Solving the system does not mean you have to invert the Laplacian matrix.